# Can functional encryption encrypt and decrypt negative integers?

Tags: encryption, public-key, number-theory, functional-encryption, quadratic-residuosity

I want to use [DCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decisional_composite_residuosity_assumption)-based [functional encryption](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/543.pdf) for encryption and decryption purpose. However, I'm unsure whether DCR-based functional encryption can support negative integers.

Is there any implementation or construction of functional encryption where negative integers are encrypted/decrypted?

Comment: Does DCR stand for [Decisional Composite Residuosity (assumption)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decisional_composite_residuosity_assumption)? Is the question related to Guilhem Castagnos, Fabien Laguillaumie and Ida Tucker's [_A tighter proof for CCA secure inner product functional encryption: Genericity meets efficiency_](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~gcastagn/publi/TCS22_IPFE_CCA.pdf), in [Theoretical Computer Science, 2022, Vol. 914, p 84-113](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2022.02.014)?

Comment: Yes. DCR stand for Decisional Composite Residuosity assumption. The question is related to any DCR based functional encryption and the paper cited is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, DCR systems can support negative integers, but just as there are limits on the sizes of the natural numbers that can be handled in the purely positive setting, the range of integers handled is also restricted.

For example, if we use the [Paillier system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem), the plaintext or operand space is $(\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z)^+$. This can be used for addition of encrypted natural numbers $x$ and $y$ by computing $E(x)E(y)\mod{N^2}$ or the product of a known natural number $c$ by an encrypted natural number $x$ by computing $E(x)^c\mod{N^2}$ provided that the answer lies in the range $[0,N)$ in both cases. Alternatively, we can restrict our answer to integers in the range $(-N/2,N/2)$. We can then implement the encryption of the negative number $-x$ as $E(x)^{-1}\mod{N^2}$ using the extended Euclidean algorithm. Similarly, we can subtract two encrypted values $x$ and $x$ by computing $E(x)/E(y)\mod{N^2}$ again using the Euclidean algorithm or the product of the negative number $-c$ and the encrypted integer $x$ by computing $1/E(x)^c\mod{N^2}$.

The same principle applies in the [Okamoto-Uchiyama system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okamoto%E2%80%93Uchiyama_cryptosystem) for example, but working mod $N=p^2q$ and with answers restricted to $(-p/2,p/2)$; or in the [Damgård–Jurik cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damg%C3%A5rd%E2%80%93Jurik_cryptosystem), but working mod $N^{s+1}$ and with answers restricted to $(-N^s/2,N^s/2)$.

(A really neat trick that not many people know is that in Paillier you can even work with rational numbers provided that the answer is of the form $a/b$ with $0<|a|,b<\sqrt {N/2}$. There's a similar result for Damgård–Jurik).